# Why did they choose $x^4+1$ for the MixColumns step in Rijndael/AES?

Tags: aes, rijndael, diffusion

In [The Design of Rijndael](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540425802) page 39, It describe the design criteria for MixColumns step

1. Dimensions. The transformation is a bricklayer transformation operatingon 4-byte columns.
2. Linearity. The transformation is preferably linear over GF(2).
3. LisDiffusion. The transformation has to have relevant diffusion power.
4. Performance on 8-bit processors. The performance of the transformationon 8-bit processors has to be high.

However, it does not said why choose modulo $x^4+1$ operation in this step. I guess it is becasue it is the simplist polynomial operation otehr than modulo $x^4$, which will cause multiple zeros. I will glad if anyone tell me my guess is wrong.

Comment: I think you mean MixColumns step. Please edit so that other people asking this question in the future can find it.

Comment: related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15850/why-is-the-polynomial-in-aes-mixcolumns-multiplied-modulo-a-reducible-polynomial/15860#15860

Comment: Yes, it is MixColumns Step. It is a severe typo, thank for correction and thank e-sushi edit this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that when you're multiplying two four-term (four-byte) polynomials together, you could wind up with a seven-byte polynomial, but you need to reduce it to another four-byte polynomial. They chose $x^4 + 1$ because

$x^i \mod (x^4 + 1) = x^{i \mod 4}$

See [this for an example.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_mix_columns)